# Andrew Ng's ML course excercise using python: gradient descent

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I have been trying to implement the solutions of Andrew Ng's exercises in python and not sure why I cannot make the gradient descent work properly. This is the code I used for gradient descent:

```
def gradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, num_iter):
  m=np.size(x,axis=0)
  for i in range(num_iter):
      hyp=np.dot(x,theta)
      theta = theta - (alpha / m) * np.dot(x.T,(np.dot(X, theta) - y))
      return theta
theta=gradientDescent(X, y, [[0],[0]], 0.01, 1500)
```

This is theta according to this code: `array([[0.05839135],[0.6532885 ]])`

The required values are: `array([[-3.6303],[[1.1664]])`

And the model looks like this: 
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lqoJ.png)

Here is the code that I have been following which uses octave:

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)

m = length(y); % number of training examples
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

for iter = 1:num_iters
    theta=theta-alpha*(1/m)*X'*(X*theta-y)
    J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta)
end

end
```

Also to find parameters I tried to use normal equation method and it gave accurate result which means rest of the code is ok.

Comment: Any pseudo-code you're following so we can check if your implementation is okay or not?

Comment: I have been using Andrew NG's implementation in ocatve

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, other than a typo on line 5 (capital `X` should be lowercase `x`), the `hyp` variable is never used, and you should pass `theta` as shape `(2,)` not `(2,1)` (i.e. as `[0,0]`).

I tried it on some toy data, seems to work:

```py
theta_true = np.array([-3.6303, 1.1664])

n = 50
X = np.ones((n,2))
X[:,1] = np.linspace(0,5, n)
ytrue = np.dot(X, theta_true)
y = ytrue + np.random.randn(n)

plt.scatter(X[:,1], y, s=100, c='b', alpha=0.4)
plt.plot(X[:,1], ytrue, 'k--')
```

[image: Scatterplot of toy data]

and ran your (cleaned up) gradient descent code:

```py
def gradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, num_iter):
    m = np.size(x,axis=0)
    for i in range(num_iter):
        theta = theta - (alpha / m) * np.dot(x.T,(np.dot(x, theta) - y))
    return theta

theta = gradientDescent(X, y, [0,0], 0.01, 1500)
theta
# array([-3.81920963,  1.22926242])
```

which seems close enough to me.

Comment: you have changed theta's dimension to 1,2 from 2,1. How did you then multiply a 97,2 matrix X with it?

Comment: This is a quirk of `numpy` - passing `[0,0]` will get treated as `(2,)` not `(1,2)`, where `(2,)` is treated by numpy as 1-dim.  So when you ask NumPy to do `np.dot(X, theta)` it automatically reshapes `theta` appropriately.   See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284995/are-1-dimensional-numpy-arrays-equivalent-to-vectors) for a longer explanation.